# sqlite + visual studio 2017

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2017

Как подключить sqlite к visual studio 2017? Что скачать? Как добавить? https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: `vcpkg install sqlite3`

Comment: На каком языке пишете? Будете ли использовать какую-нибудь ORM и т. п.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с C#

**Необходимые NuGet-пакеты для работы с SQLite**

- System.Data.SQLite
- System.Data.SQLite.Core
- System.Data.SQLite.EF6
- System.Data.SQLite.Linq

**Пример**

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source = C:\......\test.db";
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT name FROM users";

    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            names.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего - для начала - возьмите [amalgamation](https://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-amalgamation-3210000.zip), тогда вам будет достаточно подключить к своему проекту `sqlite3.c`, и добавить `#include "sqlite3.h"`.